# SonataAdmin field translatable empty

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, sonata-admin, doctrine-extensions

I have configured an Entity as translatable using Gedmo Translatable. The problem is that the translatable field is blank when I show it in the list view of Sonata.

[image]
Am I missing something?

Comment: Since all there is to see is a screen shot of list table, I should ask - What about the database? Is your translatable column empty or not? Did you tried to manually find a record and dump its translation? You are aware that Sonata's logic is just like Symfony's form builder. What does "**getTitle()**" in your main entity returns? My guess - nothing.